# Source for guest bed in Sedom as a parable for education

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzibur-community, chinuch-education, allegory-mashal, sodom-ammorah

[Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) has [quoted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48793/rav-shlomo-wolbe-and-children#comment129465_48793) R. [Yakov Kaminetsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Kamenetsky) as saying:

> R' Yaakov Kaminetsky pointed to the Gemara about the "guest bed" in Sodom, where if you were too short they stretched you; too tall, they cut off your limbs; he said this was the state of our educational system.

I'm looking for a source for this idea. This can either be a specific citation to R. Kaminetsky writing or saying it, or any source of anyone else of equivalent or greater stature saying the same thing. In measuring "equivalent or greater" the answer's subjective estimation is fine.

Comment: No I'm not the firsthand source. I've heard it quoted as such from both Rabbi Yitzchak Breitowitz and Rabbi Eli Fischer, if it helps. Would have to check with some talmidim or the like.